# Using Outlook SMTP server to send email through a contact form but unable to send as I need the server to be able to accept multiple "From" addresses

Tags: python, django, outlook, smtp

Currently using Django as the chosen framework for my project and I have implemented a contact form and my main goal is for users to complete the contact form and the admin of the site (me) get an email, which shows me the details of their enquiry.

I am trying to use the Outlook SMTP server and these are my current settings in settings.py:

```py
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'

EMAIL_PORT = 587 

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 

EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<my_emailAddress>' 

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('OUTLOOK_PASSWORD') 

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' 

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '<my_emailAddress>'
```

However, whenever I complete the form and send the request to the server I am receiving the following error code:

```
(554, b'5.2.252 SendAsDenied; <my_emailAddress> not allowed to send as <inputtedForm_emailAddress>; STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:
SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.
```

I am looking for some help surrounding this issue - it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I had same issue with Outlook.

Looks like Outlook is not accepting anymore sending emails from unsecure apps.

Your next alternative is to use `gmail` but first enable `unsecure apps` in gmail setting.

Everything should be the same, change only smtp to
​`EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`